# How can i insert a header and footer to word documents in sharepoint

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, word

We have some word docs in Sharepoint and would like to add images to the header and text to the footer.
So maybe users can select what they want to insert the text and images.
Not sure if its possible with docs in sharepoint but almost sure its possible using C#.
Any resources will be appreciated on how to approach this.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

of course you can! develop a custom solution to do this by using OPEN XML SDK

Comment: Thanks Eric can i use open xml sdk with SP2010?

Comment: sure! you can. i'm using it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you need here (unclear question), but have you looked into Content Types and their associated feature: Document Templates?

These steps are similar for SP2007 and SP2010 (in SP2010 many of the buttons are in the ribbon): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jh-zIP_YBBw

Comment: alirobe,
       Let me put it this way.I have some documents in a document library.But these doc don't have headers and footer.To automate the process. A user can select a header e.g an image and a footer some text for a particular document from the document lib and then export the document to pdf with the header and footer.Thanks